# I can't figure out if Ki Pool Increases in points every few levels beyond or stays the same

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does the Monk's Ki Pool increase with level increase or does it stay the same size through the level up system?

Answer (score 6):

### Your ki pool increases every two monk levels

From the [Ki Pool monk ability](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/monk.html):

> At 4th level, a monk gains a pool of ki points, supernatural energy he can use to accomplish amazing feats. The number of points in a monk’s ki pool is equal to **1/2 his monk level** + his Wisdom modifier. As long as he has at least 1 point in his ki pool, he can make a ki strike.

Comment: Note that the Ki pool can also increase by gaining levels in other classes, like the [Ninja](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classes/ninja.html) and the [Stalker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/stalker) (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102300/stacking-ki-pool-from-multiple-sources-in-pathfinder?rq=1) for more info).

Comment: And remember, that increasing the wisdom modifier permanently (e.g. level gain) immediately increases the Ki-Pool, while magic items (e.g. headband of wisdom) grant the benefit after 24 hours.

Comment: so you get more ki points when you get a new special quality to your ki?

Comment: The special abilities are an extra, your ki points simply increase every two monk levels, stacking with ninja and stalker levels as pointed out by @Luris.