# Calculating AC for a monk/enlightened paladin

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, paladin, armor-class, archetype

Monks get an AC bonus from WIS. The paladin archetype “Enlightened Paladin” from the Inner Sea Combat Guide gains an AC Bonus based off of CHA?

Can those stack?

Comment: How would the Ki Pools stack? Would you add both your Wisdom and Charisma modifiers to determine?

Comment: @DanceSC https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102300/28926

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**.

I thought this was going to be a complicated stacking question, but looking at the Enlightened Paladin made it really simple.  The monk's AC Bonus has always stacked with your Dex bonus to Armor Class, and the [Enlightened Paladin's Confident Defense feature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo-paladin-archetypes/enlightened-paladin-paladin-archetype/) simply adds to your Dex bonus to AC, it's not a separate thing.  So stack away ^_^

(Note that if you're choosing to wear light armor instead of no armor, you'll probably lose your monk AC bonus unless you're using a monk archetype that allows it, AND your armor's max Dex bonus will limit how much benefit you can get from Confident Defense.)

Comment: What kind of monk archetypes allow armor with the WIS bonus?

Comment: @FrancisJohn I can't think of one off the top of my head, but face it, is there ANYTHING about a class that normally goes unaltered when every possible archetype gets involved?  I'm sure there's one out there somewhere.  The "armored monk" archetype makes as much sense as the "naked paladin" archetype.

Answer (score 2):

As stated with the marked answer, **Yes**.

There is, however, one exception. If the monk takes the archetype "Scaled Fist" then it does not stack, and only the higher of the two will count because both are using the Charisma modifier for ac.

Creative Director James Jacobs:
Can you add the same ability modifier twice to the same ability? No.

http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=385?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#19247

And again at:

http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=386?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#19274

And finally:

http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=444?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#22160